# Java bringing window to front doesnt let me type in textfield

Tags: java, windows, swing, awt

I want to be able to type in textfield when my frame brought foreground. Program is set to bring my Frame to the foreground after 5 seconds and set focus on textfield. I start the program then click another window. My frame shows up after 5 seconds with cursor blinking. But when i type something it doesnt actually taken as input by textfield. I also implemented FocusListener to confirm that focus set to textfield when frame brought to foreground. My operating system is Windows 10.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TestMain implements FocusListener {
    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method should be
     * invoked from the event-dispatching thread.
     */
    public JFrame frame = null;

    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        // Create and set up the window.
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.addFocusListener(this);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Label");
        panel.add(label1);

        JTextField textField1 = new JTextField();
        textField1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 40));
        panel.add(textField1);
        textField1.addFocusListener(this);
        label1.addFocusListener(this);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            // Program Closing Alert
            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
                System.out.println("window activated");
                textField1.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestMain mn = null;
        // Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        // creating and showing this application's GUI.
        mn = new TestMain();
        mn.createAndShowGUI();

        System.out.println("START");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            mn.frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Focus Gained by " + e.getComponent().getClass().getName());

    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Focus Lost by " + e.getComponent().getClass().getName());

    }

}
```

**UPDATE :** When i add

```
frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
```

after

```
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

it works only for the first time. if i change main function as

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    mn.frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    mn.frame.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    mn.frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    mn.frame.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

it doesnt work for the second time

Comment: After you set your frame to 'always on top' request the focus on the frame.

Answer (score 0):

You do bring focus to the JTextField but you dont b ring focus to the frame itself. Bringing the frame to the front and bringing the focus to the frame is different. A solution similar can be found here: [How to set focus the already running application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937843/how-to-set-focus-the-already-running-application)

Answer (score 0):

Moving your frame doesn't focus your textfield. You should add `toFront()` after set always on top so if the Window is visible, brings the Window to the front and may make it the focused Window.

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    mn.frame.setVisible ( true );
    mn.frame.toFront ( );

} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: i've tried this but problem still remains. i've noticed that after adding "mn.frame.tofront()", when it's brought to foreground it keeps blinking on taskbar.

Comment: @Splash What about now? check my edited answer (i'm on linux and it's working, i need your confirmation)

Comment: when i change "setAlwaysOnTop(true);" with "setVisible(true);" it also doesnt work. i've put "frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );" statement after  "frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);" and it works now but i dont know if that has a side effect.

Comment: What version of the JRE are you using.  In 1.7 there is a setAutoRequestFocus on the window that should automatically receive focus on toFront()